# Does an Android class exist with similarities to both Spinner and AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, spinner, autocompletetextview

I am trying to take an `AutoCompleteTextView` and, through an `OnListItemClickListener`, return an ID from a database. To be more specific, I want a user to be able to type something in, click on one of the options that pops up, and then, rather than completing the typed word, the click returns an ID associated with that word to the user.

I know that, through a custom adapter, I can return an id through a `Spinner`, but I want a user to be able to type in what they're looking for. Is there some way to do this through `AutoCompleteTextView`, or does another class exist where I can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFIK there is no such class with both the functionalities.

You can try the following code which does that...

```
 final AutoCompleteTextView mAutoCompleteTextView;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items));

    mAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {
            mAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
        }
    });
```